# Solve $(8p^3-27)x=12p^2y$, $p=\frac{dy}{dx}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $F(x,y,p)=(8p^3-27)x-12p^2y=0$

My attempt: $F=0, \frac{\partial F}{\partial p}=0,$

Solving them i got $p=\frac{y}{x}$

Now subsituting this in above, we get $\frac{x(8y^3-27x^3)}{x^3}=12 \frac{y^2}{x^2}y \implies 4y^3+27x^3=0 \rightarrow$ this is my p-discriminant. But p-descriminant solution is given as $x(4y^3+27x^3)=0$. Pls clarify

Comment: Is it $\frac{\partial F}{\partial p} = 0$ or $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = 0$?

Comment: edited. pls have a look. it is $dF/dp$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial p}=24p(px-y)=0 \implies py=p^2x$.

Now, $(8p^3-27)x=12p^2y = 12p^3x \implies x(4p^3+27)=0 \implies x(4y^3+27x^3)=0$.

---

Observe that $py=p^2 x$ implies $p=y/x$ or $p=0$. You missed the $p=0$ case, which results in $x=0$.

Comment: thank you, i never observed various values of p must also be considered.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** With derivative of $y=\dfrac{(8p^3-27)x}{12p^2}$ respect to $x$ and simplification we find $(2xp'+p)(4p^3+27)=0$ which gives us the solutions.